# Find which Permalink structure is the best

Tags: permalinks

I have the following permalinks structure in mind for a new blog, now instead getting theoretical answers on which is best, i would like to find myself which is best in terms of speed. How can i find this? I tried using get_num_queries() but i find the results varying each time i access the blog.

Note: I am running a local XAMPP installation with WordPress on it and i am new to PHP, so any guidance is much appreciated.

/%postname%/

/%post_id%//%postname%/

/%post_id%/%postname%/

/%category%/%postname%/

I am expecting 5000 plus posts but pages wont exceed 10. Thought this might also help someone when replying back to my query. Thank You.

Comment: `/%post_id%/%postname%/` is the fastest. `/%category%/%postname%/` the slowest. `/%post_id%//%postname%/` and `/%post_id%/%postname%/` are the same.

Comment: @G.M. not that we don't trust you, but answer with _reasons_ or _benchmarks_ for that would be in order :)

Comment: Why do you think URL rewrite would be bottleneck or one of bottlenecks in your site?

Comment: @Rarst for sure, for that reason I didn't write an answer but a comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any speed differences between the various permalink structures is negligible. I mean, we're talking likely milliseconds of difference. Forget speed, just go with the structure that makes the most sense semantically for your site. On another note, it makes sense to go with a structure that will make the most sense for your users. For example, it makes sense to go with /category/post_name if you have a lot of categories/posts, as it makes navigation easier for users.